# Find value in one column in another column with regex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns of strings. I want to identify all row where the string in the first column (`s1`) appears within the string in the second column (`s2`).

So if my columns were:

```
abc    abcd*ef_gh
z1y    xxyyzz
```

I want to keep the first row, but not the second.

The only approach I can think of is to:

1. iterate through dataframe rows
2. apply `df.str.contains()` to `s2` using the contents of `s1` as the matching pattern

Is there a way to accomplish this that doesn't require iterating over the rows?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a vectorised way at the moment

Comment: @EdChum, not quite, could use `numpy.char.find()` for simple matching, if no `re` is to be involved.

Comment: If you have a really large data set, you can have a look at [Dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 3):

It is probably doable (for simple matching only), in a vectorised way, with numpy chararray [methods](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html):

```
In [326]:

print df
    s1          s2
0  abc  abcd*ef_gh
1  z1y      xxyyzz
2  aaa   aaabbbsss
In [327]:

print df.ix[np.char.find(df.s2.values.astype(str), 
                         df.s1.values.astype(str))>=0, 
            's1']
0    abc
2    aaa
Name: s1, dtype: object
```

Comment: just to update you can use `df.loc` instead of `df.ix`

Answer (score 2):

The best I could come up with is to use `apply` instead of manual iterations:

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['abc', 'xyz'], 'y': ['1234', '12xyz34']})
>> df
     x        y
0  abc     1234
1  xyz  12xyz34

>> df.x[df.apply(lambda row: row.y.find(row.x) != -1, axis=1)]
1    xyz
Name: x, dtype: object
```

Comment: sorry to break this to you but `apply` is essentially a `for` loop, the code just looks cleaner

Comment: @EdChum Thanks for the confirmation. [Dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) could potentially parallelize this though.

Comment: That's probably true as the operations are independent of each other so the task can be partitioned