# Regex in pandas to find a match based on string in another column

Tags: regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of which this is a part.

```
   CodeID    Codes
0  'code1'   '[code1(a,b,c)][code2(c,d,e)][code3(e,f,g)]'   ...
1  'code2'   '[code1(a,b,c)][code2(c,d,e)][code3(e,f,g)]'   ...
2  'code3'   '[code1(a,b,c)][code2(c,d,e)][code3(e,f,g)]'   ...
...
```

What I'm trying to do is extract the part of the string in column `Codes` that matches the pattern `r"\[<code in CodeID column>[^][]*\]"`

Something like:

```
df['Code'] = df['Codes'].str.find(r"\[<code in CodeID column>[^][]*\]")
```

[This recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339494/find-value-in-one-column-in-another-column-with-regex-in-pandas) seems to imply it's not possible in a vectorised way but it's not exactly the same situation.

Comment: If it is possible, then the regex will look like `r"\[<code in CodeID column>[^][]*\]"`

Comment: Thanks. I'm always blind to regex and leave that part of debugging till last!

Answer (score 2):

We can certainly use string from one column to compare another like below,

> In lambda expression x[0] is codeID and x[1] is codes.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

Out[20]: 
    CodeID                                         Codes
0  'code1'  '[code1(a,b,c)][code2(c,d,e)][code3(e,f,g)]'
1  'code2'  '[code1(a,b,c)][code2(c,d,e)][code3(e,f,g)]'
2  'code3'  '[code1(a,b,c)][code2(c,d,e)][code3(e,f,g)]'

df[['CodeID','Codes']].apply(lambda x: re.match(r"\[%s[^][]*\]"%x[0], x[1]),axis=1)
Out[21]: 
0    None
1    None
2    None
dtype: object
```

Well it returns None because of my bad regex skills :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extract method of pandas Series with a regular expression to extract the desired string from column Codes based on the corresponding value in column CodeID.
Here's the code to achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'CodeID': ['code1', 'code2', 'code3'],
                   'Codes': ['[code1(a,b,c)][code2(c,d,e)][code3(e,f,g)]',
                             '[code2(a,b,c)][code3(c,d,e)][code1(e,f,g)]',
                             '[code3(a,b,c)][code1(c,d,e)][code2(e,f,g)]']})

# Define a function to extract the matching pattern for each row
def extract_code(row):
    pattern = r"\[" + row['CodeID'] + r"[^][]*\]"
    match = row['Codes'].find(pattern)
    if match >= 0:
        return row['Codes'][match:row['Codes'].find(']', match)+1]
    else:
        return None

# Apply the function to each row to extract the code
df['Code'] = df.apply(extract_code, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  CodeID                                        Codes           Code
0  code1  [code1(a,b,c)][code2(c,d,e)][code3(e,f,g)]  [code1(a,b,c)]
1  code2  [code2(a,b,c)][code3(c,d,e)][code1(e,f,g)]  [code2(a,b,c)]
2  code3  [code3(a,b,c)][code1(c,d,e)][code2(e,f,g)]  [code3(a,b,c)]
```

Comment: As a reminder, [AI generated content is banned on this platform](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).